# Passing a 2 dimensional vector in Class OOP

Tags: c++, oop, class, vector, 2d

I am confused about passing a 2D vector using OOP

For example:

```
class ABC
{
public:
    void function() 
    {
     vector<vector<string>> high;
     for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
     {
         high[0].push_back(i);
     }
    }
};

int main() {};
```

In the function , I do some calculations and the results are stored in 2D-array (high). I need the whole 2-d array to pass to the main function, How can i do it ?

I tried this,

```
class ABC{
public:
    vector<vector<string>> function ()
    {
    vector<vector<string>> high;
    for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
    high[0].push_back(i);
    }
    }
};
int main()
{
ABC abc;
abc.function();
};
```

But it seems to be a total failure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your array from function like:

```
vector<vector<string>> function ()
{
    vector<vector<string>> high;
    high.resize(1);   // <-- note this resize, because you are using high[0] 
                      //     element later
    for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
        high[0].push_back("some data...");
    }
    return high;      // <-- note this return statement
}
```

Call `function` from `main` to get your data like this:

```
vector<vector<string>> data = function();
```

Other, but more efficient solution would be create your array in `main` and pass it by non-const reference to `function`:

```
class ABC{
public:
void function (vector<vector<string>>& high)
{
    high.resize(1);
    for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
        high[0].push_back("some data...");
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    ABC abc;
    vector<vector<string>> high;
    abc.function(high);
};
```

Also make sure your vector contains elements you want to access. For example `high[0]` accesses first vector element. Use `resize` to change size. Note, that `push_back` automatically increases size.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    //high[i].[j]
    //high.at(i).at(j)
```

I Think something in this way.